# Close pop up and refresh parent page javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout

So what i want to do is close pop up and refresh parent but after few seconds delay to make sure all data is received. currently i have the following

```
function closeAndRefresh(){    
  setTimeout(function()
    {     
    window.open('/{!currSubId}','_top');
    window.location = window.location.href;
    return true;
    },5000)
}
```

This code refreshes the parent but inside the popup, so the pop up does not close, rather the parent shows refreshed - in pop up

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter refers to a "window name", not a "target" (the target attribute of an anchor tag). Instead, you'd want to use something like:

```
window.opener.top.location.href = '/{!currSubId}';
window.close();
```

It's usually a bad idea to wait for any length of time as opposed to being event-driven. I'm not sure where/how you're using closeAndRefresh(), but I'd guess you want to put it either in an onComplete attribute of a Visualforce element, or some particular state of the page or an element on the page, such as window "load", XMLHttpRequest's "readystatechange", or elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer, this reloads the pop up and does not close it though..